# SDL_Mixer dll not found

Tags: c++, sdl, visual-studio-2019, sdl-mixer

Im made a game in Visual studio 2019. For that i've setup myself SDL2, SDL_image, SLD_ttf using NuGet installer in Visual studio. Now I installed SDL_mixer as well, coppied all the the mixer .dll files into the same folder as my program ( did the same thing with other SDL components as well, which worked ), but only mixer is giving me errors 'unresolved external symbol'.

I don't see reason, why SDL_mixer is doing this, and other SDL doesn't.

If you know, why this is happening, please tell me.

The .ddl files downloaded and coppied are:
*libFLAC.dll, libmodplug.dll, libogg.dll, libvorbis.dll, libvorbisfile.dll, SDL2_mixer.dll, smpeg.dll*

Comment: ***but only mixer is giving me errors 'unresolved external symbol', which means, that it can't find the definitions of functions = .dll file.*** This is wrong, unresolved external symbol errors have nothing to do with the location of the .dll files. Visual Studio does not link to .dll files (well not with standard c++) it links to .lib files which go with the .dll files. These are called import libraries.

Comment: Read about Implicit Linking here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2019)